# vb.net update table with datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I stack at my code I have a datagridview then if datagridview values has all ready in my table then update my table with datagridview value else insert into my table. But I stack at when update then the updated value just once and insert into my table when the values is not in my table failed.

Here is my table and value
 [image]

Here my code

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvLosshours.Rows
If (row.Cells("losshrs").Value = "") Then
    MsgBox("Losshours can't Empty", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Return
Else
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim hd As Integer = row.Cells("headcount").Value * row.Cells("workhrs").Value - row.Cells("losshrs").Value
    Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand
    Dim mydt1 As New DataSet
    Dim myadapt1 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    openConnectionsMySQL()
    cmd1 = New MySqlCommand("select * from whweek where periode = date_format(NOW(), '%m-%Y') ", connectMySQL)
    myadapt1 = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
    myadapt1.Fill(mydt1, "list")
    connectMySQL.Dispose()
    If (mydt1.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 19) Then
        Dim c As String = "Update whweek losshours : " & row.Cells("losshrs").Value & ", RegularHours :" & hd
            With dgvLosshours
                dt = ctrl.ActionQuery("update whweek set workhrs = '" & row.Cells("workhrs").Value & "', losshours = '" & _
                row.Cells("losshrs").Value & "', reghrs = '" & hd & "', Ke = '" & _
                row.Cells("edate").Value & "', modifyby = '" & frmMenu.toolempno.Text & _
                "', modifyon = '" & today & "' where CodeDept = '" & _
                row.Cells("dept").Value & "' and class = '" & row.Cells("class").Value & "' ")
                dt = ctrl.ActionQuery("INSERT INTO log (EmpNo, Tanggal, Ket) VALUES ('" & frmMenu.toolempno.Text & "', '" & today & "', '" & c & "')")
            End With

            MsgBox("LossHours had been updated!")
            dgvLosshours.Rows.Clear()

    ElseIf (mydt1.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0) Then

        Dim hd1 As Integer = row.Cells("headcount").Value * row.Cells("workhrs").Value - row.Cells("losshrs").Value
        Dim c As String = "Add LossHrs By :" & frmMenu.toolempno.Text & " Period : " & period
        dt = ctrl.ActionQuery("insert into whweek(codedept, class, workhrs, losshours, reghrs, Dari, Ke, createby, createon) values('" & _
        row.Cells("dept").Value & _
        "','" & row.Cells("class").Value & _
        "','" & row.Cells("workhrs").Value & _
        "','" & row.Cells("losshrs").Value & _
        "','" & hd1 & "','" & _
        row.Cells("sdate").Value & "', '" & _
        row.Cells("edate").Value & "', '" & _
        frmMenu.toolempno.Text & "','" & today & "')")
        dt = ctrl.ActionQuery("INSERT INTO log (EmpNo, Tanggal, Ket) VALUES ('" & _
        frmMenu.toolempno.Text & "', '" & today & "', '" & c & "')")
        MsgBox("Successful Save LossHours")
        dgvLosshours.Rows.Clear()
    End If

End If
```

Next

and i want to update the volume become 100 for all items and '2017-04-26' date2 for all items and when i start new date1 and date2 all items will duplicate is ok, the volume, qty, volume*qty loss stuff date1 and date2 are not same values

ex insert new data 
my query not insert to my table

[image]

update data 
my code just update the first row i want is update all row.

[image]

my code are not return those two image i want.
Please show me the way, thanks

Comment: What error are you receiving? This example is not very succinct.

Comment: Hi @DanielShillcock, I'm sorry. I will edit this post and please show the way thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i've know my answer here the code :

```
update whweek set wh= '" & dgvLosshours.Rows(intI).Cells("wh").Value & "', lh= '" & _
                                       dgvLosshours.Rows(intI).Cells("lh").Value & "', reg= '" & hd & "', Ke = '" & _
                                        dgvLosshours.Rows(intI).Cells("edate").Value & "', modifyby = '" & frmMenu.no.Text & _
                                         "', modifyon = '" & today & "', periode = '" & dgvLosshours.Rows(intI).Cells("periode").Value & "' where id= '" & _
                                         dgvLosshours.Rows(intI).Cells("id").Value & "' and class = '" & dgvLosshours.Rows(intI).Cells("class").Value & _
                                         "' and Dari = '" & dateFrom.Text & "'
```